# D3.js can't load json file

Tags: javascript, json, apache, d3.js, circle-pack

I am trying to create a D3.js [packed circle diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/seliopou/4127259).

When I embed the data in the HTML file, it works fine. When I put the data in an external file, I get nothing (blank DOM, no console msgs).

If you uncomment the var data declaration and comment out the d3.json (and the corresponding closing parentheses) it works fine.

I can see the "2013 Inf-2.json" file in the browser and it appears well formed (it passes jsonlint validation). It  includes everything from the first "{" through/including the last "}". Much as the embedded example.

I'm running this through httpd (:80) on OSX Mavericks and trying to render the chart in Chrome or Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./d3.v3.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
<body>
<div id="chart2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var w = 640, h = 480;
/*
var data ={ 
"name" : "root",
     "children" : [
  {
    "name":"URIN TRACT INFECTION NOS",
    "size":12196
  },
  {
    "name":"ACUTE PHARYNGITIS",
    "size":6679
  },
  {
    "name":"PNEUMONIA ORGANISM NOS",
    "size":6452
  },
  {
    "name":"BRONCHITIS NOS",
    "size":2636
  },
  {
    "name":"CELLULITIS OF LEG",
    "size":2348
  },
  {
    "name":"OBSTR CHRONIC BRONCHITIS W (ACUTE) EXACERBATION",
    "size":2203
  } 
]
}
*/
var data = d3.json("2013 Inf-2.json", function(error, root) {

var canvas = d3.select("#chart2")
      .append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
      .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .size([w, h])
      .nodes(data);

    // Get rid of root node
    nodes.shift();

    canvas.selectAll("circles")
        .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

 });
</script> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change line

```
var data = d3.json("2013 Inf-2.json", function(error, root) {
```

to

```
var data = d3.json("2013 Inf-2.json", function(error, data) {
```

So you just have to replace "root" with "data"

Comment: Yes, I've tired this but still get an empty page and no console msg. The API Reference appears to say "the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the parsed JSON." https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json

Comment: It is working but you have to put it on web server. It can also work this way: 
var data = d3.json("2013 Inf-2.json", function(error, data) {

Comment: Btw. in Chrome it works only if you load it from web server. In Firefox it works if you open it from file system so you do not need server. Try opening with Firefox.

Comment: Both the HTML file (containing the javascript) and the "2013 Inf-2.json" are in the same subdirectory on the webserver. I'm loading the page with htt://localhost/myfile.html. In both Chrome and Safari I get a blank page when using the d3.json. But when I use the json data embedded in the HTML it works. It's a wierd problem...

Comment: Ok, it must be something local. Thanks for testing.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on but after saving your html and js file over my own, it seems to work now. I can see no difference between your files and mine in a text editor. Very strange but working now. Thank you for helping in testing and I'll mark this post as answered.